# What is this user up to?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-abuse

I came upon [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5237598) in the review queue, and I was initially thrown - it appears that the user needed approval for modifying his own answer!  Looking closer though, revealed that it was a different user, just with the same (maybe misspelled?) username **and icon**.

Interestingly, the user had *already* posted the edit as an additional answer.  I rejected the edit with a custom message of `"What's with the same username and icon? Why not make your edit it's own answer. Otherwise, this changes too much."`, but now I'm curious... is the user somehow locked out of their original account?  Or is something else going on?

Comment: It's probably just the same user who's screwed up his account(s). His avatar is an identicon, which is based on the email address registered to that account. The fact they're the same makes the "screwed up account(s)" idea even more likely.

Comment: How did that possibly get accepted...

Comment: Both are *Unregistered* users.

Comment: @Payeli - Why? It's clearly the same person, who never registered their first account and is just following on with an additional edit. I see no harm here.

Comment: @Payeli - I restored their edit and removed the superfluous answer. I think it's a little cleaner to have all their suggestions in one place.

Comment: The use of the "you" pronoun is strange, though.

Comment: I would reject the edit saying it's a spam.

Comment: @Rahul: Then please steer clear of the suggested edit queue.

Comment: @Matt, I do indeed, go through edit/close vote/etc queue but not on a regular basis. With the above comment I mean to say, if it were me, I would reject.

Comment: @Rahul I think the remark was mostly related to the reject reason 'spam', which would be inappropriate.

Comment: @Rahul **Do not abuse the spam/vandalism rejection reason**. This reason trains the spam filter and must be reserved for actual vandalism. For example, if someone mistakenly attempts to edit a response into an answer, use the “invalid edit” rejection reason, not the vandalism reason. It's the same type of distinction as flagging as very-low-quality/not-an-answer vs. spam/offensive.

Comment: @Gilles, that's correct. I don't actually mean rejecting it cause it spam (it was just an example). I was trying to say ... I would reject the edit.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This user somehow ended up with *three* different accounts.

I've merged them together, so things should look a bit more sane now.

Comment: Ah, that explains why the same user number showed on the left and the right....

Comment: `things should look a bit more sane now` - not to people who just got into this question and thought OP was crazy :)

Comment: @KyleMit That said, it doesn't look like it's caused too much confusion so far, since the upvote-counts on both the question and the answer are identical. (...which I think is pretty cool. And yes, I did my part to preserve that.)

Comment: @KyleMit I understand what the OP means

Answer (score 0):

*(posting this mainly as a complement to [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262926/1331430))*

Presumably, you are talking about a [certain "unregistered" user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262909/1331430).

It is very easy to lose an unregistered user's authentication cookie, and someone lazy to use the recover account feature or with a fake email would just create another unregistered user account instead.

The user suggested an edit from one of their accounts other than the one they authored the post with, but now that Shog9 has merged the accounts the edit suggester and post author accounts are the same.

Comment: Why are there so many questions on meta related to this guy?

Comment: I don't know, maybe people are just curious about how "unregistered" accounts work? It is a technically new concept for me.