# How do unregistered accounts work?

Tags: support, accounts, unregistered-users

Apparently, you can have an account with badges and reputation and everything without registering. For example, this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3801037/iamdranged.

[image: Screenshot with "unregistered" circled]

What's the difference between accounts like this and normal accounts? If it has a persistent identity that other people can't just claim, in what sense isn't it registered? Are there things you can't do with an unregistered account? How does such an account get created? How is it authenticated? If you log out, are you locked out forever?

Comment: The machine only requires you to register when you *ask* a question.  Anybody that mis-spells "deranged" is allowed to post answers without registering.  Caveat emptor of course, 26 rep is not exactly a promise.  Nor a guarantee he got it wrong either.  Use your noggin'

Comment: By the way, this user no longer exist.

Comment: that freehand though...

Comment: This is second question on meta related to `iamdranged`

Comment: There profile is now [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813704/iamdranged), they got merged into 1 account.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> What's the difference between accounts like this and normal accounts?

The primary difference is that an unregistered account doesn't have login credentials associated with it. This effectively means that we don't know who you are (well, outside of having your IP address and a name/email combo you provided) and your profile may be restricted from certain actions.

*On Stack Overflow* (and a few other sites in the network), you have to log in (i.e. have a "registered" profile) before you can ask questions. Answering doesn't have the same limitation.

> If it has a persistent identity that other people can't just claim, in what sense isn't it registered?

See above: no login credentials. Usernames aren't unique on our sites, but nobody can have the same user profile id, so in essence, you claim that with your profile, registered or otherwise.

> How does such an account get created?

[image]

> How is it authenticated? If you log out, are you locked out forever?

It is cookie-based. When you log out, we remind you to register (and there are a couple other reminders), but if you go ahead and do it anyway... you can go through the [account recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) process and potentially a profile merge (I'm currently investigating if we have a bug with unregistered profile recovery) in order to regain access to your unregistered profile. After account recovery, the profile will be registered to prevent another loss of access.

Comment: "_On Stack Overflow (and a few other sites in the network), you have to log in (i.e. have a "registered" profile) before you can ask questions. Answering doesn't have the same limitation._" Apparently [not always the case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6764953/1028230), though that's from 2011 and this answer is from 2014, so I suspect a change occurred in the diff. ;^) But if someone runs into the same thing, bet the question is pre-c2014

Answer (score 8):

From the [Help Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-register) (emphasis mine)

> There are some things you **won’t be able** to do on the site without registering, however, such as vote or **ask new questions**. Registering is easy, and once logged in, you **can gain** other key **privileges** by earning reputation.

[Further](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/what-does-it-mean-when-someones-an-unregistered-user) [Clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62613/reputation-for-unregistered-account) abounds...

Comment: That page doesn't say anything about unregistered accounts. The two classes of users it talks about are registered users and anonymous contributors.

Comment: The very first word on the page is "Registration". My included quote uses the word "registering" twice

Comment: Given the contents of that help page, would you have expected that an account like the one linked in the question was even possible?

Comment: Unregistered users can't ask questions, but the can answer, and the linked user has no questions and a few answers, so yes, it all seems normal to me

Comment: Even though the page is titled "Why should I create an account", and it divides users into registered and anonymous, implying that if you do not register, you do not have a persistent identity or account?

Comment: See edit for links to similar questions

Comment: Oh, right, all the old meta posts are on SE meta now. That's why my search for dupes didn't find anything.

Comment: that page is not for unregister accounts, because I've seen some unregistered users with a lot of questions and reputation

Answer (score 3):

<sup>In addition to [Adam Lear's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262913/11682469) a little overview:</sup>

**What is an Unregistered User**

They log in providing a username and e-mail address (1). Their account is based on a long living cookie tied to a specific computer and web browser. To log in on another computer/web browser, they'd have to store their cookie and carry it with them (2). Their accounts have a profile page and can gain reputation (1) and badges (8). If control over the account is lost, they can be recovered if a correct e-mail address was provided (3, 10). Accounts can also be merged (4).

**What they can do**

- Answer unprotected questions (5, 7)
- Comment on own posts (11), everywhere in case of enough reputation (12)
- Read (like anonymous users) (5)
- Edit own posts (11), suggest edits (like anonymous users) (5)
- (accept answers to their questions) (3)

**What they can NOT do**

- Ask new questions (since 2011) (6)
- suggest edits to post less than 10 min old
- Vote (5)

  - Up- or downvote
  - Flag (3)
  - Delete own posts (9)

---

Notes:

The only way unregistered users can vote is to accept answers to their own questions. Since they were prohibited from asking new questions on Stack Overflow in late 2011, this only concerns older questions. On other stacks, unregistered users are still able to ask new questions.

---

Sources:

(1) [Reputation for unregistered account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62613)

(2) [What does it mean when someone's an Unregistered User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68524)

(3) [Why should I register my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) / [Chat message reporting a test](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55478349#55478349)

(4) [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232)

(5) https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-register

(6) [Encouraging users to create an account (and keep it)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107152)

(7) [Partial protect question hover text is irrelevant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113739)

(8) [How to recover reputation and badges from when I was an unregistered user stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73074)

(9) [Unregistered users should be able to delete their own answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50260) / [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

(10) [Any visible indication that a user is unregistered (apart from profile page)? Bounty disappears with cookie?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297305)

(11) ["Why is there no indication of an unregistered user?" Has there been any thought or discussion thereof?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304474)

(12) [Do not let unregistered users “comment everywhere” (at least on certain sites)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324771)

(13) [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899)

Comment: From [source (3)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44562): "And as flagging is a type of voting too, unregistered users cannot flag for moderator attention either." Am I correct in assuming that this means flagging in general and not just a custom or moderator flag, e. g. that an unregistered user also can't flag an answer as NAA?