# Can unregistered users ask questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, accounts

I did read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262909/how-do-unregistered-accounts-work) and its answers on how unregistered profiles work. It states that such users can answer but not ask questions with an unregistered profile.

> **Quoting Anna Lear's answer:**
>
> On Stack Overflow (and a few other sites in the network), you have to log in (i.e. have a "registered" profile) before you can ask questions. Answering doesn't have the same limitation.

Now, I am curious as to how [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/883539/joel) has asked questions in the past but is still categorized as "Unregistered" on their profile page. Was such an option available for asking questions also earlier?

[image]

Comment: Support is "a request for assistance with one of the sites features". There's nothing shameful in this and if you're asking about a current feature you don't want a discussion but to ask for support. Whether there's an obvious answer is, as far as I can tell, irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of this user's questions were posted in August 2011. At that time, you didn't need to be registered to ask questions on Stack Overflow.

The "registration required" restriction was implemented in [September 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it/107163#107163).

Comment: .. and for a note, this user isn't seen after August 2011. Gone!

Comment: Ah thanks mate. Already had a feeling that there must be something I am missing but somehow that linked post never came in my search on MSE. Will mark as accepted when it permits.