# Why are anonymous users allowed to post questions on SE?

Tags: support, anonymous-user

What I mean is users obviously not having signed up for an SE site, going by a name like "user2566091" (just made up) and lacking avatar, SE history, etc. You've all seen them, so I'm sure you know what I mean.

I'm just curious, since actual long-time members risk reputation by posting and answering questions.

Again I'm sure this was addressed in the early days of SE, it's just answers are not found on Meta.

Comment: Note that sometimes those aren't merely accounts without a custom username, but rather deleted accounts. In those cases, there won't be a link to the profile page in the user card.

Comment: Duplode’s comment illustrates that perhaps we *don’t* know what you mean. I updated my answer to cover both interpretations: active accounts that kept the default `user<userid>` name and posts by accounts that have since been deleted. But maybe you could link to an example or add a screenshot of the kind of account you were thinking of?

Comment: Not only was this addressed many times in the history of SE, answers are found on Meta, if you look in the right places.  What you may not know is that meta.stackoverflow.com previously served as meta.stackexchange.com, and all existing meta questions were sent to meta.stackexchange.com and a brand new empty meta site was created for SO-specific questions.  Since you are asking about SE in general, not SO specifically, both your research and your question belong at meta.SE

Comment: Mostly duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276088/103167

Answer (score 13):

We are all as anonymous as each other, and we are all measured by our *contributions*. The output produced by [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) is no less valuable than yours or mine. Yet they did sign up, register and have a history with the site. They just opted not to pick a username and stuck with the defaults.

And how do you *know* that you know who I am, and how can I know who you are? On the internet [nobody knows you’re a dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you're_a_dog), or an AI hosted in the cloud.  It shouldn’t matter anyway; what matters is how helpful your contributions to the site are.

Note: you can still, today, create [unregistered accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262909/how-do-unregistered-accounts-work). Unregistered accounts can have avatars, and usernames other than the default, and a SE history. The only difference is that you can’t recover the account one you log out. The default username or gravatar images are not only used by unregistered accounts and should not be seen as a sign that an account isn’t a serious, committed contributor.

Next, we keep the positive contributions from users when an account is deleted, because this site tries to collect valuable answers and all contributions are licensed to the site under the [Creative Commons license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).  However, such content is *anonymised* by having the username replaced with the default (`user<userid>`), a gray silhouette as the avatar, no reputation score or badges, and the usercard is not linked:

> [image: anonymised usercard]

The user did exist at some point but is now gone, only their contribution remains. Because why throw that away?

And finally, when the card says *Anon* instead of `user<userid>` the. The post [has been *disassociated* from an account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0), usually at their request:

> [image: anonymous usercard]

There is no option to start a post in this state, there is no feature to post anonymously. Disassociation is not a lightweight and easy process and it is possible that the original account can still be found if your search hard enough.

There is also a temporary unlinked state for the authors of migrated posts from another site, waiting for the author to create a local account. In that case an actual username will be shown.

Comment: "And how do you know that you know who I am" I know that you are in fact a ninja.