# Two users with the same name

Tags: support, users

It seems like one person has created two users. Perhaps due to a misunderstanding.

- [Ralph Emerson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6525622/) (unregistered)
- [Ralph_Emerson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6529498/)

Ralph The Second [has edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12853219) the answer of Ralph The First.

What to do in such cases?
And why does the first Ralph has the word `unregistered` in brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to disagree with Servy here. If we all followed that advice, the edit would wait around in the queue forever. And it opens the door for bad things to go unnoticed.

I ran into the same situation before. I flagged the post with:

> This user seems to have created another account, maybe by accident. See this suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12500107

It was marked helpful.

The issue isn't that the user has created another account (which is allowed, as long as it's not a sock puppet). The issue is that this *could* be a bit bigger than a simple blunder with accounts:

- Is the user trying to farm rep? Remember, approved edits give the user +2 rep.
- Will the user continue to suggest these edits, and waste reviewer's time?
- Does the account belong to somebody else entirely? It's not super crazy to think somebody might be trying to impersonate another user, in the hopes that reviewers would approve the edit.

As a normal user, you just don't know (unless it's a name like ["John"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?search=john), which is common enough to be a coincidence). The proper course of action is to contact a mod, so that they can ensure all is in order. The mod should be the one who decides that nothing needs to be done, not you (since you lack the mod tools needed to deal with this properly).

Comment: In reference to your suggestion here, many of the flags I raise now (albeit infrequently) are custom when I encounter genuinely puzzling or interesting edge cases (like this one). They are almost always marked helpful, because as you note, it is good to moderator eyes on these slightly strange situations.

Answer (score 7):

> What to do in such cases?

Nothing.

> And why first Ralph has the word unregistered in brackets?

Because they created an unregistered account to post an answer.

For reference: [How do unregistered accounts work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262909/how-do-unregistered-accounts-work)

Comment: Could Ralph register his unregistered account instead of creating a new one?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky He could, if he wanted.

Comment: Your first point is not entirely accurate. There is not supposed to be interaction which leads to reputation between accounts, and an edit for a lower reputation user is +2. This, while seemingly minor, constitutes abuse.

Comment: @TravisJ That's assuming the edit is approved.

Comment: @Servy - "which leads to reputation". Even if not realized it is still inappropriate and shouldn't be left unattended. At the very least there should be some sort of warning or explanation issued to the user about cross account activity like this.

Comment: I don't see this particular case as really needing any kind of intervention other than maybe an acct merger so that it would be easier for him to edit his post and allow him to comment on it. It appears as though he simply asked a question without an account, then later decided to make one and edit his question.

Comment: oops, answer, not question. :)

Comment: I see. I think I misunderstood the overall situation in that I was unaware you could post an answer as an unregistered user. So in this case, it seems the user cannot technically benefit as they don't seem to have access to both accounts.