# Duplicate answer, second account: NAA or Rude/Abusive?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Coming back from reviewing [this particular case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18541610). The answer is copy-paste given to one question by, evidently, the same user under different accounts with 1 hour time difference.

Not to be nitpicking for the sake of it, but still guessing, is this better qualified as NAA or is it a form of abuse, considering 2 accounts / same answers?

[image: Duplicate]

Comment: Mod flag it when you see misuse of multiple accounts.. there is little meta can do

Comment: Neither of them. Both flags would end up being declined. Use a custom flag and explain that it's a duplicate answer posted by a duplicate account.

Comment: One of the accounts is ["unregistered"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262909/how-do-unregistered-accounts-work), so *technically* it would not be a duplicate account...

Comment: I see. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Not seeing anything malicious here, except maaaaaaybe for the fact that the older answer was already downvoted at the time it was edited and then later reposted. But considering the newer answer is actually owned by the registered account, not the unregistered one, it might just have been the user getting lost in the registration process. All in all, a bizarre sequence of events, so neither NAA nor rude/abusive would be appropriate here.

Comment: Mind that even if that user created two accounts and posted the same answer twice, NAA would still be incorrect. Both posts are valid answer posts (in scope of the "not an answer" ruleset).

Comment: All of my "duplicate account" custom mod flags have been accepted as *helpful*.

Comment: Did the same, flag accepted, duplicate answer removed.

Comment: duplicate account with the same user name sounds like an honest mistake. If you really want to fake 2 users, you create 2 accounts with 2 different pseudos.

Comment: That's true, no question on this was raised. The question was regarding proper actions when stumbled across two answers by same user with different accounts, with no morale/intentions involved.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have to spend more than a few seconds thinking about it, it's probably better to just flag it for moderator attention and move on. As BoltClock [noted in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362127/duplicate-answer-second-account-naa-or-rude-abusive#comment549464_362127) it's not uncommon for someone to become disenfranchised from their account which leads to strange things like:

- Re-posting of an answer since they can no longer see it was deleted since the new account doesn't own it
- Someone with an identical display name suggesting an edit that they seem to have written (but just with another account)

... it can smell kind of off, but it's usually benign. Anyway, there's no way for you to know given the tools that you have, so let mods sort it out.

If it seems *really* urgent, use the contact link and let us know about it directly (ideally, after flagging it too).

Comment: Yeah, all of this sounds reasonable, comments nailed it too.

Comment: Tim - you say "if it seems *really* urgent, use the contact link" - does the CM team really want that in their queue. Depending how full our queue is we might not get around to it for a bit (but is the ticket support any more expedient or necessary)#, we do however have the tools to review it and escalate *if necessary*.  Would you mind clarifying that a bit please?

Comment: "usually benign"  sums it up completely.  Never attribute to malice that which can be explained by error/accident/etc.

Comment: good point, @Criggie. We should be aware, though (and nonetheless), what to do even when this kind of situation is a pure accident, which this question is all about.

Comment: @JonClements I usually recommend doing both because it gives the issue a better chance of coming to light quickly. There's a 50/50 chance it'll get buried in the 'other' queue for a few days, and a 30/70 chance it'll get buried in our incoming queue for a few days, but if you split the odds by doing both, you actually stand a good shot at getting it seen in 24 hours. We need better tools overall, essentially, and that's my way of working around it for cases that might be more urgent than others.