# How did this user with an unregistered account ask a question?

Tags: support, accounts

[Julie Raswick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395371/julie-raswick) is an "unregistered account" with only one question and no answers.

According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262913/2912665) answer:

> "On Stack Overflow (and a few other sites in the network), you have to log in (i.e. have a "registered" profile) before you can ask questions."

If this is a requirement by design, how could Julie post a question without registering?

Comment: This rule was not in effect back in 2010. Unregistered accounts were actually able to post.

Comment: @double-beep Please post an answer so that the question can be closed

Comment: Jeff Atwood changed it in [September 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107163) when the daily question volume had increased to 4k-5k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by Adam Lear you mention in your question is from 2014, while Julie Raswick (the unregistered user) posted a question in 2010. The rule was not in effect then. Users were allowed to ask questions even if they were unregistered.

Users were also able to just type their name and email and post a question. Their profile appeared like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIuPW.png), but they had a real username (e.g. Jon Doe) and not user123456. This apparently stopped because of spam or because the bad questions were increased.