# Identify registered users in Users table

Tags: support, data-explorer, registration, unregistered-users

I'm not sure whether this has been asked already...
I was wondering if it is possible to discern "registered" from "non-registered" users in the table `Users` on https://data.stackexchange.com/.

I have tried the following constraints, assuming that a non-null `LastAccessDate`, the presence of upvotes or downvotes, a reputation greater than zero could be used to identify registered users:

```
select count(distinct AccountId) from Users
where 
LastAccessDate IS NOT NULL
and 
LastAccessDate>CreationDate
and 
(UpVotes>0
or DownVotes>0)
and
Reputation>0
```

Am I on the right path? What's the definition of registered user?

Comment: As rene has explained, the only difference between unregistered users and registered users is the credential (i.e. cookie-based credential vs email/OAuth credential). Note that unregistered users can have more than 1 rep, upvotes, and even downvotes.

Comment: This had nothing to do with defending the unicorn, right? :)

Comment: @Scratte noo it was just for my personal interest during these holidays 

Comment: Of course. Just needed to ask since I recall defending the unicorn with something about registered accounts. I however did not use SEDE for any of my answers ;) I used the hints provided in the [Winter Bash 2020](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117306/winter-bash-2020) chat room :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an unregistered user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14831372/dsdsds) and this is what their [user record](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1352764) looks like:

[image]

So, no. You can't distinguish registered from unregistered accounts in SEDE.

The difference between registered and unregistered is whether there are login credentials stored in the profile, as explained by Adam Lear in [How do unregistered accounts work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262909/how-do-unregistered-accounts-work). That fact isn't publicly available in SEDE.

The [/users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users) endpoint in the SE API return [users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) and that does offer the user_type field containing  unregistered, registered, moderator, team_admin, or does_not_exist.  (info kindly provided by double-beep).

Comment: Thanks very much! I guess I'll have to look for this information somewhere else.

Comment: It's possible to distinguish a registered from an unregistered user via the SE API. Any method that returns a list of [users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) will also return (by default) a `user_type` field which can be `unregistered`, `registered`, `moderator`, `team_admin`, or `does_not_exist`.

Comment: @user2314737 in case you missed the comment from double-beep, the API does offer the user-type. I missed that as I only checked if it was possible to search on user_type. I didn't check if the records themselves offered that data. Amended the answer a bit.