# Is there a reputation requirement for deleting your own answer?

Tags: support, answers, vote-to-delete, unregistered-users

Earlier today, I came across [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66238741/466862) that was edited to *"--- transformed to comment ---"* by its author. I asked the author of that answer to delete it instead, but they answered that they couldn't delete it, and showed a screenshot to that effect. See the following screenshot of their answer (including their screenshot):

[image: screenshot of answer with text "--- transformed to comment ---", including a screenshot of that same answer posted by the user, without Delete button]

As you can see, their view of their screenshot of their answer doesn't show a *Delete* button. The user has 32 reputation points, and is an unregistered user. Is there a reputation limit that prevents them from deleting, or is there a different reason that they can't delete their own answer (e.g. does being unregistered prevent deletion)?

Specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers says:

> Answers can be deleted at any time by their authors, *unless* the
> answer has been accepted by the question asker.

Comment: You verified the user didn't accidently create two user profiles?

Comment: Probably something to do with the fact that they're unregistered?

Comment: Unregistered users can't delete their own content.

Comment: @SecurityHound Both the asker and the person editing, and committing are the same user id.

Comment: It wasn't (initially) clear the author vandalized their answer

Comment: @cigien Is that documented anywhere, because it is not listed in [How do unregistered accounts work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262909/how-do-unregistered-accounts-work), nor on https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-register

Comment: Well, it *kind of* says so in the help page. It says unregistered accounts can't *vote*, and since deleting *is* voting, they can't delete posts.

Comment: They seem to have vandalized all of their Answers. Including the [accepted community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66215415/12695027). The others are [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66242219/12695027) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66238741/12695027). They seem determined to leave while having all of their content deleted (by Stack.. which is us, in the queues.)

Comment: @cigien I don't see why that would include your own posts, because deleting questions requires 10,000 reputation, but users with less reputation are able to delete their own questions.

Comment: @Scratte I hadn't noticed that. I'm going to rollback some of those edits then.

Comment: You're right, it's not at all clear from the current wording. I found an [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347821) asking for the help-pages to be made clearer (for deleting questions, but there's a link on that post to another MSE post about deleting answers). In fact, a moderator could just go ahead and edit the SO help-pages if they feel it's worth clarifying this edge case.

Comment: My question seems to be a cross-site duplicate of [Why can't a user delete their own question that was just asked and has had no activity?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13683/why-cant-a-user-delete-their-own-question-that-was-just-asked-and-has-had-no-ac)

Comment: This would be closer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273440 but yeah, basically the same thing. Actually, since we can't close cross-site duplicates, maybe I'll answer this one :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I see. There's even more nuance to the rules than I thought. Is clarifying this in the help-pages worth the effort? I guess this is not something that affects a lot of users.

Comment: @cigien: looks like I might be wrong on that count, I've retracted my comment to see what is going on with unregistered users and deletion.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: perhaps a better cross-site dupe would be [Allow unregistered accounts to delete their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273440)?

Comment: And Jeff indeed confirms it requires the ability to vote at [Unregistered users should be able to delete their own answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50260)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, no worries. I dug through MSE a bit, and I couldn't work out the rules well enough to write up a comprehensive answer. I would have assumed it's clearly documented *somewhere*, but apparently not, and we just have to piece together the whole story.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The user in question is *unregistered*. That's why they can't delete their own post. There's no reputation requirement.

From the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222) to the MSE FAQ [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) under "When *can't* I delete my own post?":

> *Unregistered* users (users who haven't registered their account - that is, associated a Google, Facebook, or Stack Exchange account with it) can't delete any of their own posts.

Jeff Atwood [confirms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50271)

> Cookie-based accounts don't support voting, therefore they don't support deletion.

(credit goes to [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) for digging up Jeff's explanation)